# Python: How can I indent two "if" statments

Tags: python, indentation

I am following a tutorial in French about Python and both in IDLE and the terminal, I have some problems.

Picture from tutorial

[image]

My attempt who failed

[image]

I cannot go to my second if condition without printing `pos`. Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Maybe try `ctrl+Enter`?

Comment: just use your terminal

Comment: 1. Don't post links to code. 2. Don't post pictures of code

Comment: If your editor's terminal/repl annoys you, you can always write a `.py` file using any old text editor and then run Python on that file. Of course the interactivity you get from a live terminal is hard to live without.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn how to post formatted code in your questions so that you don't have to post links to other sites. The goal is to make your question as easy to answer as possible.

You are wanting to see whether or not variable `a` is greater or less than 0 and then to print something. Right now your code is saying the same thing twice:

```
if a > 0:
    print('pos')
pos

if a > 0:
    print('pos')
pos
```

Your code as it is written now, will never print out your other `if` statement even if you had written it because you have said that `a = 5`. So your code is saying 'a IS greater than 0 so I'm going to print "pos" '. You need to say that `a = <negative number>` so that your other if statement will be true once you have written it. Then your program will analyze the first if statement, see that it is not true, and move onto the next one, see that it is true and print whatever you have in the `if` statement.

Comment: But the thing is why in this picture my second if cannot be in the same block than the first if ?

Comment: It can be, however you are using the terminal and posted them in a separate block. This isn't the problem, the problem is that you have made `a` be a number and unless you change `a` again and reinitialize your if statements you are going to continue getting the same output. Get a text editor that saves your code so you can run it without having to retype it over and over. I use Brackets but there are many others.